# How to launch 64 bit version of javaw.exe from CreateProcess (C++)

Tags: 64-bit, createprocess, javaw, syswow64

I am writing a launcher in C++ to launch my java based GUI application on Windows. I am using `CreateProcess` to launch "javaw.exe". Everything works except for the fact that 32-bit version of "javaw.exe" is always launched.

When java is installed, it puts the executables "java.exe" and "javaw.exe" in `%windir%\System32` on 32-bit windows. On 64-bit windows, it puts the same executables in `%windir%\SysWow64`.

There are 3 possibilities:

1. 32-bit launcher executed on 32-bit windows: `%windir%\System32` is in search path, and 32-bit javaw.exe is found. The GUI launches. Everything works.
2. 32-bit launcher executed on 64-bit windows: `%windir%\System32` is in search path. `%windir%\System32` is redirected to `%windir%\SysWow64` (since my launcher is 32 bit in this case). 32-bit javaw.exe is found. The GUI launches. Everything works.
3. 64-bit launcher executed on 64-bit windows: `%windir%\System32` is in search path. No redirection happens. It does not contain the executable javaw.exe. The launcher fails.

How do I launch 64-bit javaw.exe in the third case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution (by digging through various posts on stackoverflow).

Recent versions of JRE when installed do put a copy of "javaw.exe" in System32. The previous versions of 64 bit JRE probably didn't (not sure).

In any case, the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/JavaSoft/Java Runtime Environment` has a property `CurrentVersion` which points to the key for the default JRE for the system. The sub-key corresponding to the version number has a property `JavaHome` which points to the location of JRE installation.

If JRE/JDK is not installed, then the `Java Runtime Environment` key won't be found.